# Save As path to original form location - VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to get my Save As path to open up as the same folder the original document was opened from. For example, if the file was in public/forms I want it prompt save as in public/forms. Currently it is defaulting to mypc/documents. This is my code:

```
Dim IntialName As String
Dim fileSaveName As Variant


InitialName = Range("d1") & "_" & "#" & Range("l1") & "-" & "RW" & 
Range("q1")
fileSaveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=InitialName, _
filefilter:="Excel Macro-Enabled Workbook (*.xlsm), *.xlsm")


If fileSaveName = False Then
       Exit Sub
End If

If Not fileSaveName = False Then
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Application.ThisWorkbook.Path & 
fileSaveName
    Else

         On Error Resume Next
         If Err.Number = 1004 Then
         On Error GoTo 0
Else
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Application.ThisWorkbook.Path & 
       fileSaveName
End If
End If
```

Thanks!

Comment: Use `ChDir ActiveWorkbook.Path` before calling the dialog.

Comment: @braX: This doesn't work if you are dealing with different drives

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below will save to the file name you've used.  I've made it reference the ranges on Sheet1 rather than whichever sheet is currently active when your execute the code.  Change the sheet name as required.

It will also open to the folder that the file containing the code is in (`ThisWorkbook`).
Change this to `ActiveWorkbook` or any other path as required.

```
Sub Test1()

    Dim InitialName As String

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        InitialName = .Range("D1") & "_" & "#" & .Range("L1") & "-" & "RW" & .Range("Q1")
        InitialName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & InitialName
    End With

    InitialName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialName, "Excel Macro-Enabled Workbook (*.xlsm), *.xlsm")
    If Not InitialName = "False" Then
        ThisWorkbook.SaveAs InitialName
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry for the noob question but would this code completely replaced my current code? I don't see my InitialName to draw the inputted information on my form. Thanks.

Comment: Have updated my code so should work as desired - was having a mindfart with my first block of code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `InitialName` contains only a filename without path, change the parameter `InitialFileName` to

```
Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:= thisWorkbook.Path & "\" & InitialName, ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

File filter can take a full folder in the initial path, so you can assign it based on the workbooks path

```
Dim InitialName As String
Dim fileSaveName As Variant

Dim FilePath, FileOnly, PathOnly As String

FilePath = ThisWorkbook.FullName
FileOnly = ThisWorkbook.Name
PathOnly = Left(FilePath, Len(FilePath) - Len(FileOnly))


InitialName = PathOnly & "\" & Range("d1") & "_" & "#" & Range("l1") & "-" & "RW" & 
Range("q1")
fileSaveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=InitialName, _
filefilter:="Excel Macro-Enabled Workbook (*.xlsm), *.xlsm")


If fileSaveName = False Then
       Exit Sub
End If

If Not fileSaveName = False Then
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Application.ThisWorkbook.Path & fileSaveName
    Else

         On Error Resume Next
         If Err.Number = 1004 Then
         On Error GoTo 0
Else
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Application.ThisWorkbook.Path & fileSaveName
End If
End If

fileSaveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=InitialName, _ 
   filefilter:="Excel Macro-Enabled Workbook (*.xlsm), *.xlsm")
```

Comment: I get a compile error for the following line: InitialName = PathOnly & "\" & Range("d1") & "_" & "#" & Range("l1") & "-" & "RW" & 
Range("q1")

Comment: Same results as my original code, save as opening in mypc/documents.